# Different confidence with same model.pb from android and python

Tags: tensorflow

I trained a model.pb with python, and put it in android.
well, I find the confidence score that in android is always lower than python application on my PC.
AFAIK, for android model.pb, I did not use DecodeJpeg because it not support on Android.

Is there anything wrong or different with DecodeJpeg in android example when processing image?

```
Trace.beginSection("preprocessBitmap");
// Preprocess the image data from 0-255 int to normalized float based
// on the provided parameters.
bitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
for (int i = 0; i < intValues.length; ++i) {
    final int val = intValues[i];
    floatValues[i * 3 + 0] = (((val >> 16) & 0xFF) - imageMean) / imageStd;
    floatValues[i * 3 + 1] = (((val >> 8) & 0xFF) - imageMean) / imageStd;
    floatValues[i * 3 + 2] = ((val & 0xFF) - imageMean) / imageStd;
}
Trace.endSection();
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry my fault that set  imageMean = -127 , imageStd = 127.

I just did not know the meaning below code, before .

```
for (int i = 0; i < intValues.length; ++i) {
    final int val = intValues[i];
    floatValues[i * 3 + 0] = (((val >> 16) & 0xFF) - imageMean) / imageStd;
    floatValues[i * 3 + 1] = (((val >> 8) & 0xFF) - imageMean) / imageStd;
    floatValues[i * 3 + 2] = ((val & 0xFF) - imageMean) / imageStd;
}
```

well now I understand that , this means convert RGB values to [-1 ~ 1]

whtch TensorFlow can read. So imageMean  should be  imageMean = 128 and  imageStd = 128 just like the  example code  in official github of
 TensorFlow .or you can use below for more accuracy:

```
    floatValues[i * 3 + 0] = (float) ((((val >> 16) & 0xFF) / 255.0 * 2.0) - 1.0);
    floatValues[i * 3 + 1] = (float) ((((val >> 8) & 0xFF) / 255.0 * 2.0) - 1.0);
    floatValues[i * 3 + 2] = (float) (((val & 0xFF) / 255.0 * 2.0) - 1.0);
```

**Because of accuracy problem, the result is still not same as Python TensorFlow result, but they have been infinitely near each other.**